# How to format the value in tooltip axispointer echart (angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here's the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-echarts-zn8tzx?file=src/app/app.component.ts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kYa6.png)

What I want here is to format and insert the text upload and download below the date and time.

for example:

```
2020-02-04 12:00:02
UPLOAD
流量: 28

2020-02-04 12:00:02
DOWNLOAD
降雨量: 32
```

Comment: You need to provide a context for your problem, and not just dump code and let everyone figure it out

Answer (score 0):

update the names inside `this.options.series.name`

which will become:

```
  dynamicName1 = 'upload 流量';
  dynamicName2 = 'download 流量';
  ...
    series: [
        {
            name: this.dynamicName2,
            type: 'line',
            symbolSize: 8,
            hoverAnimation: false,
            data: [...]
        },
        {
            name: this.dynamicName1,
            type: 'line',
            xAxisIndex: 1,
            yAxisIndex: 1,
            symbolSize: 8,
            hoverAnimation: false,
            data: [...]
    }
]
...
```

your [stackblitz updated here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-echarts-4bs4ck)

[image]

Comment: what I mean sir is to add a new line for the UPLOAD and DOWNLOAD

Comment: How to insert the text UPLOAD and DOWNLOAD below the dateandtime

Comment: did you run my stackblitz? do you mean something different from my answer and the screenshot that I added?

Comment: it should the upload is in the middle of ```date``` and ```流量```

Comment: so it should be ```dateandtime```, ```UPLOAD``` then the ```流量```

Comment: you can see it on my example sir

Comment: open the stackblitz code which i have pasted in the answer... and add `流量` after the upload (in `name` field of the 2 objects in the series)

Comment: but it should be dynamic sir. example on my legend it should be ```流量``` and ```降雨量```. not ```流量``` and ```download 降雨量```

Comment: it is dynamic now, please check